# android sort integers from database from big to small

Tags: android, database

I made an quiz android app where the user get score every time he finish the quiz and after that the score will be saved in the database and after that the user can display the saved score. and my question is how I can display or sort these score on the page score from the biggest score to the smallest. 
this is my code where I get the score and name of the user and set it on a textview:

```
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    DbHelper info = new DbHelper(this);
    userInfo.open();
    String data = userInfo.getData();
    userInfo.close();
    tv1.setText(data);
```

my getData method:

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID2, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
        Cursor c = ourDbase.query(MyTABLE, columns , null, null, null, null, null);
        String result ="";

        int TheRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
        int TheName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int TheScore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(TheRow ) + " " + c.getString(TheName ) + " " + c.getString(TheScore ) + "\n"; 
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your getData() method?

Comment: @jvrodrigues the code in my question is for getting the data from the database, I didn't use getData() method.

Comment: How does it get the data? 

Im assuming it queries the database. The last argument in the query refers to the order, so just add Table.COLUMN_YOU_WANT_ORDERED + " DESC" to the query call.

Comment: @jvrodrigues oh I am sorry I found the getData method

Comment: Post it and lets see it!

Comment: @ jvrodrigues I added the method in my question.

Comment: did you even consider taking a quick peek at the documentation for the `query` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set ascending or descending in the last argument of your query. In your case, your getData() method can return your string with the KEY_SCORE column in descending order by changing the query line to this:

```
Cursor c = ourDbase.query(MyTABLE, columns , null, null, null, null, KEY_SCORE + " DESC");
```

Good Luck!